# CopyOfRange for 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Is there any similar command to `Arrays.copyOfRange(short[] original, int from, int to)` for 2D arrays in Java?

If there is not, is there any straightforward way to copy columns or rows of 2D array without using for loops?

Comment: I think for loops are your best bet with this kind of problem... I bet `Arrays.copyOfRange` is uses for loops too...

Comment: Without using for loops at all?  Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

> copy columns

1) you can copy columns just using Arrays.copyOfRange

```
    String[][] sss = { {"1", "2"}, {"3", "4"}};
    String[][] sss1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(sss, 0, 1); // ss = {{"1", "2"}}
```

2) for copy rows without loop you can use Stream Api

```
 Arrays.stream(sss).map(s1 -> Arrays.stream(s1).skip(1).limit(1).toArray()).toArray(); // return {{"2"},{"4"}}
```

3)  "This does a shallow copy;"

Ok, use Stream Api we can do not shallow copy:

```
Arrays.stream(sss).skip(1).limit(1).map(s1 -> Arrays.stream(s1).toArray()).toArray(); // return {{"3", "4"}}
```

Comment: I think you've trivially demonstrated a copy of rows here.

Comment: This does a shallow copy; if you modify a row in `sss1` it will change `sss`, which doesn't sound like what the OP wants.